# Размер APK файла в Android Studio намного больше, чем в AIDE. Как уменьшить размер пакета?

Tags: java, android-studio, apk, filesize

Один и тот же код. Простейшее приложение с двумя TextView и Button и Activity классом. 
Собираю release в Android Studio, в AIDE и Codenvy (Eclipse Che). Proguard minify включен.

В итоге в AIDE и Codenvy размер APK файла 15 - 30 Кб, а в Android Studio - 1.5 Мб.
После установки соответственно 56 Кб и 3-4 Мб.

Вопрос: возможно ли и как уменьшить размер APK компилируемого с Android Studio?

Comment: есть предположение, что студия автоматом добавляет support library.

Comment: Уже пробовал вычищать v7, которую студия добавляет к проекту. Всё равно не выходит.

Comment: 15-30 кб как то очень мало. Может эти среды немного "обманывают"? А по поводу студии - открывайте gradle файл и вычищайте оттудова.